# Dialog not appearing on Page load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a php page that inserts data into database and after insertion it redirects to another page, I want that while the data is being inserted i could show user a dialog box, The insertion takes almost 2 minutes, So I wrote this code at start of page

```
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
<script>
    function dialogsf() {
        $("#loadingsf").dialog({
            hide: 'slide',
            show: 'slide',
            autoOpen: true
        });
        $("#loadingsf").dialog('open').html("<p>Please Wait...</p>");
        alert("dfsd");
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        dialogsf();
    };
</script>
<body>
    <div id="loadingsf" title="Import"> 
        <p>Please wait ...</p>
    </div>
```

No dialog appears while the insertion is taking place, I tried `javascript:dialogsf()`; from the URL tab and then I can see the dialog box, Am i missing something?

Comment: What's the relation to the PHP tag?

Comment: @Fred-ii- because I am writing all this in a php page and may be some php guy have encounter the same problem , though its not related to php but who knows whats the actual reason and it is not destructive in any way ;)

Comment: Can you try jquery's ready method?

Comment: @parixit just tried that and it same response, nothing happen..

Comment: The problem is probably somewhere else. Check your error console.

Comment: @user1765876 Try adding a `$(document).ready` something to the affect of `$(document).ready(function dialogsf()) {` instead, see if that helps.

Comment: This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/XRXMk/) works...

Comment: @user1765876, try to reproduce this in a jsFiddle, then.

Comment: @Fred-ii- now this something amazing, I commented my function that actually inserts data into the DB and now I can see the dialog box, The thing is that I want that while the data is being inserted into DB I can see the dialog box,.

Comment: @user1765876 ah... so now we're getting somewhere then. Have you considered using Ajax instead? That would simplify things and you could use most of what you already have.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I can't use ajax because that would complicate things more, I cant explain all that here but in short authorization issues etc

Comment: @user1765876 I understand. Trying to think how it could work from what you asked me above. Thinking...

Comment: @user1765876 I have something that I can show you as a **"suggestive"** answer, or I can make a Pastebin file. I just don't want people to possibly "downvote" it. But, a method I use does work for me, although it's not jQuery but you can base yourself on the idea.

Comment: @user1765876 as an answer, or Pastebin?

Comment: @Fred-ii- as an answer is better

Comment: @user1765876 Done, have a look below.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i cant use ajax , anyways thank you so much

Comment: @user1765876 You're welcome. Yet you can "base" yourself on it. You don't have to use the Ajax that's in it. I'm sure it can be replaced by a regular JS method. I just never got around to it to changing it to regular JS.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following for script.  `<p>` and `</p>` tag is there in dialog open.

```
function dialogsf() {
        $("#loadingsf").dialog({
            hide: 'slide',
            show: 'slide',
            autoOpen: true
        });

        $("#loadingsf").dialog('open').html("Please Wait...");

    }

$(function () {
    dialogsf();
    });
```

Check it in jsfiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/parixit572/WNQ3B/1/

Comment: its because of PHP , I can even see the dialog box by javascript:dialogsf()

Comment: then post your php code also. So that we can analyze that also.

Comment: its a simple PHP insert function that keeps on inserting value in DB and also echo them on page..

Comment: does that echo goes in dialog's html? And are you doing it with ajax or page refresh?

Comment: that echoes goes simple on page , echo '$abc'; nothing else, no its not through page refresh

Comment: Can you check your browser console. If there is any javascript error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36624/discussion-between-parixit-and-user1765876)

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTE:** This is a "Suggestive" answer, used as an example.

Here's something that I use while uploading files and it works for me and you can base yourself on this idea.

The popup box that appears while everything is happening, automatically disappears once my upload has finished, and could work for you also.

### HTML

```
<div id="load" style="display:none;"><br><br>Uploading... Please wait.<br><hr><br>Do not close this window until it has finished.</div>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit="return checkFields();">

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value=" Click here to UPLOAD when ready " />
```

### CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
#load{
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
border:3px double #999;
background:#f7f7f7;
width:300px;
height:300px;
margin-top:-150px;
margin-left:-150px;
top:50%;
left:50%;
text-align:center;
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", verdana, arial,tahoma;
font-size:18pt;
}
</style>
```

### JS

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var ray={
ajax:function(st)
    {
        this.show('load');
    },
show:function(el)
    {
        this.getID(el).style.display='';
    },
getID:function(el)
    {
        return document.getElementById(el);
    }
}
</script>
```